# Win32 WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP and statuses getting "stuck"

Tags: c++, winapi

Below is a code I use to capture what ever the key is being pressed or not and I update the statuses of the keys according to their states.
I keep the statues in my simple array of values 0,1,2,3.
formatted as: keyboardmap[256] = {0};

Problem is, what ever I try to do, keys keep getting stuck at some point. They never get reset back to zero as if the WM_KEYUP would not fire up properly.

```
  while (true)
  {

    if ( PeekMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE) )
    {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);

      if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
      {
        break;
      }

      // Check for keystates and update them.
      if (msg.message == WM_KEYDOWN)
      {
        // Fetch the key state.
        unsigned int keycode = msg.wParam;
        unsigned int cstate = engine.GetKeyState(msg.wParam);

        if (engine.GetKeyState(keycode) == 0)
        {
          engine.SetKeyState(keycode, 1); // Just started pressing.
        }
        else
        {
          engine.SetKeyState(keycode, 2); // Actively pressed down.
        }
      }
      else if (msg.message == WM_KEYUP)
      {
        // Fetch the key state.
        unsigned int keycode = msg.wParam;
        unsigned int cstate = engine.GetKeyState(msg.wParam);

        if ( engine.GetKeyState(keycode) == 2)
        {
          engine.SetKeyState(keycode, 3);
        }
        else
        {
          engine.SetKeyState(keycode, 0);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: are you aware that this loop eats 100% of the CPU? `PeekMessage` is non-blocking. Have you considered using `GetMessage` instead?

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, I will limit that later on, this is a for real-time game.

Comment: The system already tracks keyboard state. Pointless for you to do likewise. 100% CPU is surely avoidable.

Comment: Try GetAsyncKeyState.

Comment: You are trying to re-invent [GetKeyboardState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299.aspx). Besides that, games usually handle input differently, and use a lower-level API like [DirectInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416842.aspx) or [Raw Input](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645536.aspx).

Comment: MSDN states that for keyboard and mouse, DirectInput should not be used.I will try to fizzle with GetKeyboardState. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: The code is just buggy.  You hope to get *two* WM_KEYDOWN messages so the key state will be 2.  But that won't happen if you don't hold the key down long enough for it to repeat or if you press another key quickly enough.  So you'll never set it to 3 when the key goes up.  How it gets from 3 back to 0 is not obvious either, you are not going to get two WM_KEYUP messages.  Start fixing it by eliminating state 2, that is never going to be reliable because it requires a timer.

Comment: *"DirectInput should not be used"* - Well, that's what the MSDN says. Anything that hasn't been introduced in Windows 8 or above (or received a major update) is tagged *legacy*. However, without a clearly communicated successor, no one is going to jump ship. At a guess, DirectInput is good for another decade.

Comment: I ended up switching the whole thing to this: for (int k = 0; k < 256; k++)
{ engine.SetKeyState(k, GetAsyncKeyState(k)); }

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good solution but hey you seem to know more than us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how the message loop is supposed to be. Use the following example for a game engine where you need to constantly update the game/screen:

```
WNDCLASSEX wc = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";
RegisterClassEx(&wc);

CreateWindow(...);

MSG msg = { 0 };
//while (msg.message != WM_QUIT) <=== removed in edit
while(true)  //<=== **** edit **** 
{
    if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        if(msg.message == WM_QUIT) //<=== **** edit **** 
            break;
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        engine.update();
    }
}
```

Window's messages should be handled in separate window procedure:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```